# Получить sizeof

Tags: c#

sizeof(_asm_ret)

как мне перевести это в C#?

```
bool BlockAPI_mono(HANDLE hProcess, char* api_name)
{
    CHAR _asm_ret[] = { 0xC3 };

    char* mono_patch = GetModulePatchByName(hProcess, "mono.dll");

    if (mono_patch == NULL)
        return false;

    HMODULE mono_lib = LoadLibraryA(mono_patch);

    if (mono_lib == NULL)
        return false;

    FARPROC func = GetProcAddress(mono_lib, api_name);

    if (func == NULL)
        return false;

    DWORD dwOldProtect = 0;
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(func), sizeof(_asm_ret), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect);
    bool write = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(func), reinterpret_cast<LPCVOID>(_asm_ret), sizeof(_asm_ret), 0);
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(func), sizeof(_asm_ret), dwOldProtect, &dwOldProtect);

    return write;
}
```

Comment: Не надо это переводить, потому что опкод инструкции ret (0xC3) занимает ровно один байт.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как мне его в C# прописать не подскажите?Хочу mono_runtime_invoke блокнуть,но код на C++ только есть

Comment: Что прописать? Вместо sizeof что в сишном, что в C#-коде напишите число 1.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов так я получаю ошибку "int" в "System.UIntPtr"

Comment: Если у вас где-то ошибка - надо что-то исправить. Почитайте в правилах про вопросы типа "почему этот код не работает"...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Сколько я не искал ненашел не 1 темы по детекту инжекта через моно

Comment: Ваш вопрос об инжекте, о том как сделать sizeof в C# или о неведомой ошибке в неведомом коде? Сейчас это вопрос о sizeof.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов делаю защиту от mono инжекта.Не знаю как указать sizeof в C# - ставя 1 получаю ошибку  "int" в "System.UIntPtr"

Comment: VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, memLoc, 1, PageReadwrite);

Comment: А где у вас декларация VirtualProtectEx?

Comment: [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool VirtualProtectEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress,
            UIntPtr dwSize, uint flNewProtect, out uint lpflOldProtect);

Comment: Интересно, зачем size_t превратился в int*, фактически?..

Comment: я не знаю [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]  скопировал с сайта iv**ke.net

Comment: ну по идее new UIntPtr(sizeof(_asm_ret)), тогда ошибка уйдет. Но я не уверен, что у вас правильная сигнатура. Попробуйте

Comment: @Александр да не нужен там ни Ptr, ни sizeof. В третьем параметре - размер памяти. Размер инструкции ret - 1 байт, это количество, а не указатель. MSDN тоже говорит что третий параметр - число, а не указатель на число.

Comment: Я знаю, просто погуглил. И наткнулся на несколько примеров деклараций тоже с IntPtr вместо размера. При чем судя по всему примеры рабочие. Согласен, что int просится

Comment: Можете поделиться рабочим примером блока инжекта?Знал про способ через callback AssemblyLoad,но появился способ его скрыть